# Access Hash inside helper of another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-hash

I currently have a helper titled directors_helper.rb with a hash predefined inside of it.

```
module DirectorsHelper
   def dirs = {
      gm: { pos: "General Manager", email: "123@abc.com" },
      prod: { pos: "Production Director", email: "456@def.com" },
      support: { pos: "Support Director", email: "789@xyz.com" }
   }
   end
end
```

Anything under the directory /app/views/directors is able to access the content of the helper and thus the hash. Any attempt to call `<%= dirs[:gm][:pos] %>` inside a directory thats not directors gives me the error `undefined local variable or method 'dirs'` Is it possible to have my hash  globally accessible throughout my project?

Comment: Where did you learn to define a `Hash` like that?

Comment: I picked up a Rails project with only C++ experience... I am going off of code that was already provided to me. Is there another data type that would better suit what I'm trying to accomplish? What's wrong with how it's written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was as simple as going into the controller of the page that I wanted to have access to the directors helper and including `helper DirectorsHelper` in it.